# Defining a bijection to prove isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I'm trying to prove the graphs above are isomorphic to each other but I'm struggling with defining the bijection from the vertex set of F to the vertex set of G, ie

$\phi(a) = ? $     , $\phi(b) = ?$ , ..., $\phi(e) = ?$, $ \phi(1) = ?$, ..., $ \phi(4) = ?$

Both graphs are 3-regular and so I couldn't use the degrees of the vertices to help determine this. What's a simple way of determining an appropriate mapping?

Comment: General hint: draw graph $F$ but leave off the labels attached to the vertices— so just the edges and the nodes. Now start labeling the vertices using the labels of $G$ as well as the adjacency relations from the graph of $G $ you are given. If you can complete this, you will see an isomorphism explicitly.

Comment: @Oiler should the labeling be specific? In other words, can I choose to label whichever node I want as "a"? (and start from there)

Comment: Sure. But it’s possible that it may not lead to an isomorphism. It should be noted that this method is pretty inefficient, but it shouldn’t be too bad when the graph is relatively small.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!